# How do I properly use AngularJS $http.post to update MySQLi table through PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs, post, mysqli, http-post

I want to update a MySQLi table `achievements` through PHP. The app is coded in AngularJS and measures various statistics. When a goal is met, I send the information to a PHP script using AngularJS's `$http.post`. PHP should then handle the information and update my table accordingly. The `$http.post` returns a success message, but the table is not updated. I am confident the database connection info is correct.

My AngularJS `$scope.updatePhp` function using `$http.post`:

```
$scope.updatePhp = function(table, column, value, whereColumn, whereValue) {
    $http.post(
        "update-data.php", {
            'table': table,
            'column': column,
            'value': value,
            'whereColumn': whereColumn,
            'whereValue': whereValue
        }
    );
}
```

My AngularJS `$scope.updatePhp` function without using the `.post` shortcut:

```
$scope.updatePhp = function(table, column, value, whereColumn, whereValue) {

    console.log("Updating. Table: " + table + ", column: " + column + ", value: " + value + ", where: " + whereColumn + ", whereValue: " + whereValue);

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'update-data.php',
        data: { table: table.toString(), column: column.toString(), value: value.toString(), whereColumn: whereColumn.toString(), whereValue: whereValue.toString() },
        headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' } 
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("Success.");
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("Error.");
    });

}
```

My entire PHP file 'update-data.php`:

```
<?php

    //CORS header stuff
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    //PHP posted info
    $info = file_get_contents('php://input');

    //Update the table
    $hostname_DB = "databaseHost";
    $database_DB = "databaseName";
    $username_DB = "databaseUser";
    $password_DB = "databasePass";
    $portnum_DB = "databasePort";
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($hostname_DB, $username_DB, $password_DB, $database_DB, $portnum_DB ) or die(mysqli_error());

    $table = $info->table;
    $column = $info->column;
    $value = $info->value;
    $whereColumn = $info->whereColumn;
    $whereValue = $info->whereValue;

    $query = "UPDATE '$table' SET '$column' = '$value' WHERE '$whereColumn' = '$whereValue' ";
    $mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_error());  

?>
```

I am using the PHP error_log and I am getting this error for each variable `table`, `column`, `value`, etc.:

`PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'table' of non-object in /update-data.php on line 16`.

There is definitely something wrong with the way the info is being posted or with how the posted info is being retrieved, not with the SQL.

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide in sorting out this situation!

Comment: what is ```"port#"```? Shouldn't it be 3306 or your db server's port number?

Comment: `port#` is, of course, my port number. It's not really relevant to the question, thanks though.

Comment: Did you try to log the resulting `$query` and execute it directly against the database in some sql tool?

Comment: can you try something like ```$query = "UPDATE `$table` SET `$column` = `$value` WHERE `$whereColumn` = `$whereValue` ";```

Comment: @Naveen - I did not get different results, unfortunately.

Comment: @Florian Lim - Good call, I see that I am getting a #1064 error when using the phpMyAdmin SQL tool. I assume the error is that I used single-quotes for the query, like this:

`UPDATE 'achievements' SET 'Goal' = '1' WHERE 'id' = '1'`

when the query I actually want is

`UPDATE achievements SET Goal = 1 WHERE id = 1`

as the `Goal` is a boolean value and `id` is an integer.

Comment: @FlorianLim I ran `console.log("Query: 'UPDATE " + table + " SET " + column + " = " + value + " WHERE " + whereColumn + " = " + whereValue + "'");` in my AngularJS and got the following result: `Query: 'UPDATE achievements SET Goal = 1 WHERE id = 1'` which should be fine...

Comment: can you try ```return mysqli_error($mysqli)``` in your update-data.php instead of ```die(mysqli_error())```

Comment: @RandallArms That looks like you logged that in JavaScript. You should log the resulting `$query` in your php file and then modify it until you get the desired result. I've not used PHP in a long time, so I can't help with the syntax.

Comment: @Naveen @FlorianLim I am using the PHP error_log and I am getting this error for each variable: `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'table' of non-object in /update-data.php on line 16`. There is definitely something wrong with the way the info is being posted or with how the posted info is being retrieved, not with the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the way the data came formatted. Here is my `$info` variable printed:

`{"table":"achievements","column":"Goal","value":1,"whereColumn":"id","whereValue":"1"}`

The string from `file_get_contents('php://input')` was encased in curly-brackets, and comma-separated each value, both of which I had to remove.

I also had to get rid of the quotes for each string key-value pair, and since all I wanted was the value, I had to get rid of everything from the `:` and before (the 'key' if you will).

Here is my (albeit hacky) result, which worked excellently:

```
//PHP posted info
    $info = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $dataArr = explode(',',$data);

    $dCount = 0;
    foreach ($dataArr as $datum) {
        $newDatum = substr($datum, strpos($datum, ":") + 1);
        $newDatum = str_replace(array('}', '{', '"'), '', $newDatum);
        $dataArr[$dCount] = $newDatum;
        $dCount++;
    }

    $table = $dataArr[0];
    $column = $dataArr[1];
    $value = $dataArr[2];
    $whereColumn = $dataArr[3];
    $whereValue = $dataArr[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the error is in $.param().

```
        data: $.param({ table: table.toString(), column: column.toString(), value: value.toString(), whereColumn: whereColumn.toString(), whereValue: whereValue.toString() })
```

$.param() is a JQuery function.

Check this :

[AngularJSParamSerializer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Try without json encode/decode to see if it works.

**EDIT (comment by answerer):** "In your php try to `echo file_get_contents('php://input') ;` And in javascript in the callback of the request `console.log(response);` To see if some data is successfully sent."

Comment: No luck, even if I send the data without the `$.param()` in the `$http()` post data & without the `json_decode()` in the `update-data.php`. My `$http()` function gives an error callback without any info printed to the PHP `error_log`. Though I have removed the `param`/`json_decode` stuff as I am sure you are correct on this point.

Comment: In your php try to " echo file_get_contents('php://input') ;"
And in javascript in the callback of the request " console.log(response);" To see if some data is successfully sent.

Comment: My console logged the following response on the callback: `Object { data: "", status: 200, headers: xd(), config: {…}, statusText: "OK", xhrStatus: "complete" }`. I am not entirely sure how to see the contents of the PHP echo, though, since `upload-data.php` is just a straight PHP file opened from the AngularJS request.

EDIT: Now that I look at the response, it does have `data` as empty...

Comment: Expanding `config{...}` in the callback has the following section, which shows the data IS there:

`config: {…}`
`data: {…}`
`column: "WingedShoes"`
`table: "achievements"`
`value: 1`
`whereColumn: "id"`
`whereValue: "1"`

Comment: I selected this answer for the bounty and accepted answer as it has been the most helpful, however I am still experiencing some difficulties (though your help has gotten me closer, I feel).

Comment: I decided to use `error_log()` to log both `$info` and `$query` from my `update-data.php` file. The logged `$info` variable IS complete: `{"table":"achievements","column":"VaultoDiamonds","value":1,"whereColumn":"id","whereValue":"1"}` but the logged `$query` is empty: `Logged query: UPDATE '' SET '' = '' WHERE '' = ''`, which explains the `Trying to get property of non-object` error I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

Try not using $.param() for data. Yo can send the data object directly.

```
$scope.updatePhp = function(table, column, value, whereColumn, whereValue) {

console.log("Updating. Table: " + table + ", column: " + column + ", value: " + value + ", where: " + whereColumn + ", whereValue: " + whereValue);

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'update-data.php',
    data: { 
        table: table.toString(),
        column: column.toString(),
        value: value.toString(),
        hereColumn: whereColumn.toString(),
        whereValue: whereValue.toString() 
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' } 
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log("Success.");
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log("Error.");
});

}
```